# How do you increase the length of a line in Adobe After Effects?

Tags: after-effects

How do you increase the length of a line after creating one? I have tried trim paths and stroke, but I don't know how to do it. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You created the line with a path inside a shape layer? You can select one of the points and drag it to the new position. (use the pen tool and you should be able to select either points)